# Fecha equivocada

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy realizando un programa php+mysql, y haciendo un formulario donde tengo que introducir una serie de datos, mi código hace algo que no debería hacer, es decir, todos los campos de mi formulario deben estar rellenados para poder realizar la alta de un nuevo dato, no obstante, aunque no ponga la fecha y le de al alta, me la acepta y me pone una fecha por defecto, 1/1/1970, cosa que esta mal, ya que al darle al botón de alta, me debería de saltar un error al instante en la misma pagina y decirme debo de rellenar los campos, ahora bien, lo mas raro de todo, es que si introduzco por ejemplo, un 1 o un carácter cualquier, me da una fecha ubicada en el mismo año en el que estamos. En conclusión donde necesito ayuda es el porque mi programa me toma esas fechas por buenas cuando debería directamente rechazarlas y pedirme que introduzca un dato correcto que ingresar.

Adjunto mi código:

```html
<?php

require_once('Ninos.php');
$modeloNinos = new Ninos();

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    //PASAMOS LOS DATOS
    $datosNino = [];
    $datosNino['nombre'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nombre', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $datosNino['apellido'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'apellido', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $datosNino['nacimiento']= date("Y/m/d", strtotime($_POST['nacimiento']));
    $datosNino['comportamiento'] = $_POST['comportamiento'];
    try 
    {
        //LLAMAMOS Y REALIZAMOS LA INSERCIÓN DE DATOS
        $id = $modeloNinos->insert($datosNino);
        if ((int) $id) 
        {
            $mensajeOK = 'EXITO: Niño nuevo añadido a la base de datos';
            header('Refresh: 1; URL=indexNinos.php');
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception $ex) 
    {
        $mensajeKO = $ex->getMessage();
    }
}

?>
<!--CREAMOS EL HTML-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
       <?php echo Utils::getHead('Alta Niño'); ?>
       <link href="assets/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Estonia&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--ALMACENAMOS LOS DATOS-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-6 col-md-4 offset-md-4 mt-4">
                    <h1 class="text-center mt-4 bg-secondary rounded-pill">Alta Niño</h1>
                    <!--Si ha tenido exito-->
                    <?php if (isset($mensajeOK)) { ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            <?php echo $mensajeOK; ?>
                        </div>
                    <!--Si no ha tenido exito-->
                    <?php } else if (isset($mensajeKO)) { ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            <?php echo $mensajeKO; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <!--CREAMOS EL FORMULARIO-->
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 offset-md-4">
                    <form action="crearNinos.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group text-white rounded">
                            <label for="nombre" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa nombre" />
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-white">
                            <label for="apellido" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Apellido</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingresa apellido"/>
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-white">
                            <label for="nacimiento" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nacimiento" name="nacimiento" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"/>
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-white rounded">
                            <label for="comportamiento" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Bueno/Malo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="2" id="comportamiento" name="comportamiento" placeholder="Bueno = Sí / Malo = No" />
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right text-dark w-50 mb-2"><i class="bi bi-plus"></i> Crear</button>
                        <a href="indexNinos.php" class="btn btn-warning float-right mb-2 w-50"><i class="bi bi-arrow-left"></i> Cancelar</a>
                        </div> 
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Los campos **DATE** en MySQL se guardan en formato `Y-m-d`. Y aunque sea VARCHAR, por cuestiones de estandarización, deberías guardarlo en ese formato. Si el campo es DATE y le estás mandando "Y/m/d" a lo mejor está dando error y por eso está insertando ese valor default que dices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear el input de tipo `date` y agregar el atributo `required`.  Algo asi:

```html
<?php

require_once('Ninos.php');
$modeloNinos = new Ninos();

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    //PASAMOS LOS DATOS
    $datosNino = [];
    $datosNino['nombre'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nombre', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $datosNino['apellido'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'apellido', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $datosNino['nacimiento']= date("Y/m/d", strtotime($_POST['nacimiento']));
    $datosNino['comportamiento'] = $_POST['comportamiento'];
    try 
    {
        //LLAMAMOS Y REALIZAMOS LA INSERCIÓN DE DATOS
        $id = $modeloNinos->insert($datosNino);
        if ((int) $id) 
        {
            $mensajeOK = 'EXITO: Niño nuevo añadido a la base de datos';
            header('Refresh: 1; URL=indexNinos.php');
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception $ex) 
    {
        $mensajeKO = $ex->getMessage();
    }
}

?>
<!--CREAMOS EL HTML-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
       <?php echo Utils::getHead('Alta Niño'); ?>
       <link href="assets/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Estonia&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--ALMACENAMOS LOS DATOS-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-6 col-md-4 offset-md-4 mt-4">
                    <h1 class="text-center mt-4 bg-secondary rounded-pill">Alta Niño</h1>
                    <!--Si ha tenido exito-->
                    <?php if (isset($mensajeOK)) { ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            <?php echo $mensajeOK; ?>
                        </div>
                    <!--Si no ha tenido exito-->
                    <?php } else if (isset($mensajeKO)) { ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            <?php echo $mensajeKO; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <!--CREAMOS EL FORMULARIO-->
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 offset-md-4">
                    <form action="crearNinos.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group text-white rounded">
                            <label for="nombre" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa nombre" />
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-white">
                            <label for="apellido" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Apellido</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingresa apellido"/>
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-white">
                            <label for="nacimiento" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="nacimiento" name="nacimiento" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required />
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-white rounded">
                            <label for="comportamiento" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Bueno/Malo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="2" id="comportamiento" name="comportamiento" placeholder="Bueno = Sí / Malo = No" />
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right text-dark w-50 mb-2"><i class="bi bi-plus"></i> Crear</button>
                        <a href="indexNinos.php" class="btn btn-warning float-right mb-2 w-50"><i class="bi bi-arrow-left"></i> Cancelar</a>
                        </div> 
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```